# How to determine in what key I'm playing by moving capo to 3rd fret?

Tags: acoustic-guitar, capos

If I put capo on the 3rd fret of my guitar, what would be the key that I'm playing in? What would be a chord progression in that key?

Comment: Yes you were right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever key you were playing in before the capo, add three semitones. C major becomes E♭ major, and so on. A minor becomes C minor, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If you played a C chord shape with your capo on the third fret, then that would sound as an Eb chord.